# Play Framework 2.5 subproject port configuration

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm working on a project which contains 4 subprojects:

```
root-project:
-backend (play)
-frontend (play)
-akka-system (scala akka)
-common (messages to communicate between play projects and akka)
```

I configured runAll task in Build.sbt such way:

```
val runAll = inputKey[Unit]("Runs all subprojects")

runAll := {
  (run in Compile in frontend).evaluated
  (run in Compile in backend).evaluated
  (run in Compile in `akka-system`).evaluated
}
```

The question is how could i pass -Dhttp.port argument in task to run frontend different port than backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
runAll := {
  (run in Compile in frontend).partialInput(" 5000").evaluated
  (run in Compile in backend).partialInput(" 6000").evaluated
  (run in Compile in `akka-system`).evaluated
}
```